# How to get the old root back after `chroot(2)` given some file descriptor to it?

Tags: linux, debian, filesystems, security, python

How can I get the old root back after `chroot(2)` given some open file descriptor to it?

In the below program, I first open a file descriptor to `/`, and then `chroot(2)` to `.` and `chdir(2)` to `/`.

However, if I then `chdir(2)` to the old root of `fd`, Python complains that it cannot print the current working directory `getcwd()`, since it doesn't exist.

Why can't I change the current working directory to the old root and print it?

> This is why we have "pivot_root()" and "chroot()", which can both be
> used to do what you want to do. You mount the new root somewhere else,
> and then you chroot (or pivot-root) to it. And THEN you do
> 'chdir("/")' to move the cwd into the new root too (and only at that
> point have you "lost" the old root - although you can actually get it
> back if you have some file descriptor open to it).

https://yarchive.net/comp/linux/pivot_root.html

**Program**:

```
import os

print(f'cwd: {os.getcwd()}')

fd = os.open('/', os.R_OK, os.X_OK)

os.chroot('.')
os.chdir('/')

print(f'cwd: {os.getcwd()}')

os.chdir(fd)

print(f'cwd: {os.getcwd()}')
```

**Output**:

```
$ sudo python3 chdir_fd.py
cwd: /home/admin/projects/linux-pwn
cwd: /
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "chdir_fd.py", line 14, in <module>
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three issues I can see:

- you're using `chdir(2)` on a file descriptor. The correct system call should be [`fchdir(2)`](https://manpages.debian.org/fchdir.2).

  Although it might be possible python is smart enough to use `fchdir()` instead.
- After using `fchdir(2)` you have to `chroot(2)` again so you current directory is again *inside* the "known space" of the current *root* tree.
- You can't distinguish the result with `getcwd()`. In both cases you would get `/` even if it's not the same `/`. You could for example display the inode number (assuming it's the same filesystem so the comparison stands) or anything else that can differ.

Here, with above's changes, from a debian bullseye/sid, I chroot inside the root of an LXC buster container. I display the content of `/etc/debian_version` twice:

```py
import os

print(f'cwd: {os.getcwd()}')

fd = os.open('/', os.R_OK, os.X_OK)

os.chroot('.')
os.chdir('/')

print(f'cwd: {os.getcwd()}')

debfd=open("/etc/debian_version","r")
print(debfd.read())
debfd.close()

os.fchdir(fd)
os.chroot('.')

print(f'cwd: {os.getcwd()}')

debfd=open("/etc/debian_version","r")
print(debfd.read())
debfd.close()
```

Result:

```
root@glasswalker:/var/lib/lxc/buster-amd64/rootfs# /tmp/chrootback.py 
cwd: /var/lib/lxc/buster-amd64/rootfs
cwd: /
10.8

cwd: /
bullseye/sid
```

---

Trivia

It's possible to abuse the "unknown space" to escape a `chroot()` *without* having kept back a file descriptor. It's described in this page from 2005:

[How to break out of a chroot() jail](http://www.ouah.org/chroot-break.html)

Except for two issues in the given code (one has to add `#include <stdlib.h>` and correct the double quote typos at the `fprintf()` in line 62), it still works fine on today's Debian (and certainly a few *nixes).

From my understanding, it appears that when being in "unknown space" (ie: situation leading to OP's error when the *cwd* is outside the current *root*) one can then move blindly back to the actual *root*.

Comment: Thank you! Do you know why it’s necessary to `chroot(2)` again? I mean, do you know why is it necessary for Linux to have the cwd inside the “known space” of the current root for operations like `os.getcwd()` to succeed?

Comment: Yes: because when you're outside of the current (ch)root tree, this directory can't be resolved from /

Comment: Python should indeed be smart enough to call `fchdir()`, since Python 3.3.: https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.chdir

Comment: @ilkkachu - `help(os.chdir)` says that `os.chdir()` may be given a file descriptor on platforms that support it. It was therefore I used this function.

Comment: @A.B - Do you have any idea on how to accomplish what Linus describes as "**The smallest part, in fact. And you should be aware that root can always
get out of a chroot() if he just has enough tools - and the tools aren't
even very big. "mknod" + "mount" will do it even in the absence of a way
to add binaries, as will /proc access).**"? How can `mknod`+`mount` be used to to break out of `chroot`, if the `/dev` directory is not present? Also, `/proc` may be used to escape the jail by `cd /proc/<pid>/root`?

Comment: I don't know what Linus had in mind. I can just tell that compiling and using the program in the Trivia [link](http://www.ouah.org/chroot-break.html) (with corrections applied) is enough for root to escape a chroot.

Comment: @A.B - Alright, it also seems that calling `os.chdir('/')` after `os.chroot('.')` is not necessary, since the `cwd` is already within the new root. So, the code can be simplified.